# PostgreSql + C#:Design Time Support in VS2008

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net, dataprovider

I've installed Npgsql Data Provider for .net and I've executed

```
gacutil -i Npgsql.dll
```

as the user manual said, but I can't use the Dataset designer. When I add a TableAdapter to the designer, It ask me for a new connection, but the options are Access, MS Sql, or SQLite (other dataProviders that already i have installed). There's no option for PostgreSql. Also when I try to add a reference to Npgsql to my project, I have to search for the dll, It doesn't appear in the .Net tab of the "add a reference" menu.

What i'm missing?

Comment: Looking for an answer on the same issue. Did you find anything?

Comment: sorry, no solution found yet. :( In fact my company change to sql-server for this reason. Please, if you find something, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

this thread is a year old, but, nevertheless, pgfoundry haven't created yet a DDEX for postgres, something that is the answer to your question...
To create a DDEX, I downloaded the EFSampleProvider from msdn, where it gives you a sample to begin with.